# как сделать градиент c краёв к середине?

Tags: java, android

Я делаю стиль активити. Для этого использую XML файл в котором описываю то, что мне нужно и устанавливаю его в бекграунд самого активити

**вот так выглядит XML файл со стилем**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:thickness="0dp">

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Но таким образом у меня градиент идет сверху вниз

**вот так**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно сделать так, чтоб градиент шел от левой и правой стороны к центру

**вот так**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде как-то так, используя `android:centerColor`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#00ff00"
        android:endColor="#0000ff"
        android:startColor="#0000ff"
        android:angle="180">
    </gradient>

</shape>
```